# Equivalent of html body replace in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the equivalent to this in jquery?

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("text1", "text2");
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
$("body").html(function(){
   return $(this).html().replace("text1", "text2");
})
```

The callback function will return the current html replacing the text and the value will set as html.